# Aircrack deauth doesn't have any effect

Tags: aircrack-ng

I have spent the day trying to run aircrack on my Raspberry Pi. Everything seems to work, airodump-ng shows all the access points in the area and the aireplay-ng deauth doesn't give me any error messages. I set the channel with **'sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 6'** then issued a deauth with **'sudo aireplay-ng -0 10 -e  -c  wlan0'** . I've tried two laptops and a mobile, changing the respective MAC addresses but I can see no change. Even after 100 deauths the WIFI stays on. What am I doing wrong? Here's the output:

```
pi@pi ~ $ sudo aireplay-ng -0 5 -e mywifi -c 00:3b:3b:c4:6a:f0 wlan0
18:03:24  Waiting for beacon frame (ESSID: heisenberg) on channel 6
Found BSSID "7B:6A:23:64:ea:ea" to given ESSID "mywifi".
18:03:25  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [00:3b:3b:c4:6a:f0] [47|87 ACKs]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well dear wifi will not get turned off it will simply disconnects all the devices connected to it...sometimes disconnection is not shown by pc or computer instantly so to check..try to use internet on the device.. it must not work...

Answer (score 1):

The standard usage is:

```
aireplay-ng --deauth 100 -a (mac adress) wlan0/mon0
```

and remember that its send 100 packet usually 2 packet in second and wifi get disconnect and remember airodump-ng wlan0/mon0 must be **active** when you use aireplay-ng .